BIND9, IXFR and "rndc reload"
I'm running BIND9 docker image with a simple zone file "example.com" with the following configuration:
zone "example.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/example.com";
    ixfr-from-differences yes;
}

Then, I updated this zone (serial number increase + one record change) and reloaded the zone (rndc reload example.com). By doing "dig @localhost example.com ixfr=my-old-serial-here", I was expecting the see only the record I changed but I got the same result than AXFR (full zone).
The documentation of "ixfr-from-differences" explains:
When [...] the server loads a new version of a primary zone 
from its zone file or receives a new version of a secondary 
file via zone transfer, it compares the new version to the 
previous one and calculates a set of differences

How a server can load a new version from the file except with "rndc"?
What did I miss to make IXFR working in this case?

Does your server actually create the /etc/bind/example.com.jnl journal file?

@u1686_grawity no it does not, I was expecting BIND to create it since (from what I understood) IXFR is generated based on this journal file

Okay, and does it have permissions to create files in /etc/bind? (If not – can you move the zone file to some other place where bind/named does have permissions?)

@u1686_grawity yes that was the issue! Thank you
